# Is it possible to display on the product page in block "Related Products" products descriptions?

Tags: product, product-collection, product-relations

Is it possible to display on the product page in  block "`Related Products`" products descriptions?

The name of the related products displayed:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()); ?>
```

Description related products I tried to take:

```
<?php echo $_item->getDescription(); ?>
```

didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that not all attributes are used in a collection.

There is a function `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()` which is used to add attributes to a collection and the related products collection is no different.

There are a few things to do here but I think what would work well would be to set the attribute as `used_in_product_listing` and then you should simply be able to call.

`$_item->getAttributeCode()`

Answer (score 0):

This is because related product collection do not contain `description` attribute. However you can use `short_description`. I think that would be enough for your.

In order to show `short_description`, use this code

```
 <?php  echo $_item->getShortDescription();?>
```

in appropriate place inside

```
app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work